# Building a custom kernel metapackage

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, kernel, metapackages

I followed the [BuildYourOwnKernel](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel) guide and produced

```
linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-159-generic_4.15.0-159.167+custom_amd64.deb
linux-modules-4.15.0-159-generic_4.15.0-159.167+custom_amd64.deb
linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-159-generic_4.15.0-159.167+custom_amd64.deb
...etc...
```

Now I would like to also produce `linux-generic`, `linux-headers-generic`, `linux-image-generic`, etc. that depend on these packages.

As a hint, `apt source linux-image-generic` redirects me to `linux-meta` which it tells me is on Git:

```
NOTICE: 'linux-meta' packaging is maintained in the 'Git' version control system at:
git://git.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux-meta/+git/bionic
Please use:
git clone git://git.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux-meta/+git/bionic
to retrieve the latest (possibly unreleased) updates to the package.
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? Why do you need these custom files?

Comment: @David Immediately I'm working with Bionic but I want to be able to move forward to Focal.

I have a custom kernel hosted in a private apt repo. I want `apt upgrade linux-image` to correctly install my custom kernel, not the one from the main repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just run:

```
apt source linux-image-generic
cd linux-meta-[0-9]*/
dpkg-buildpackage
```

It very quickly produces many `.deb` metapackages in the parent directory. I believe it uses the latest entry in the `debian/changelog` file to determine which kernel packages those metapackages rely on.

I also had to patch the control files to change one of the dependencies because my custom kernel is unsigned, [discussed over on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72070720/modify-a-line-in-a-particular-section-of-a-document-with-sed).